# Не выравнивается блок посередине

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сделать выравнивание элемента по середине через `margin: auto`, не через flex

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content"> 
 
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Блок `.content` всё время прилипает к верху

Comment: margin: auto не выравнивает по вертикали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старый добрый способ позиционирования блока по вертикали и горизонтали используя `vertical-align` и `text-align`, когда еще не было `flex`-модуля. Преимущество в том, что внутренний блок с текстом при наполнении способен растянуть родительский блок, что не работает в варианте с абсолютным позиционированием.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0; height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="content"> 

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
}

.content{
  margin: 13% auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Элемент не ставится в центр, это отчётливо видно

Comment: я сделал под свой монитор, попробуйте менять проценты

Comment: Нужен универсальный метод

Comment: обязательно использовать margin? нельзя например top и left?

Comment: @ArturHarutyunyan, сразу видно новенького в вебе)

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов для автоматического выравнивания по центру использовать позиционирование

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content"> 
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

если у тебя враппер имеет четкие ширину и высоту, выставь в контенте марджинами (лефт и топ) нужные позиции и все...

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас высота блока уже задана в 50% от родительского контейнера, то достаточно сместить его на 25% вниз, чтобы он оказался вертикально посередине: `position:relative; top: 25%`

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content"> 
 
 </div>
</div>
```